# Provider not set or invalid in metamask

Tags: web3js, metamask

I'm using metamask to connect to rinkeby network. I can see metamask injects web3 code just fine, still I get the `Error: Provider not set or invalid`. Here's the js script I wrote.

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3();

if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    console.log("Using web3 detected from external source like Metamask");
    web3 = new Web3(web3.setProvider(web3.currentProvider));

} else {
    console.log("Using localhost");
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
}

var account = web3.eth.accounts[0];

console.log(account);
```

Here's the error I'm getting

[image]

I'm using webpack, web3 0.20.4. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually shouldn't be setting a provider within a `new Web3` instance if you already have the `web3.currentProvider`.

Replace:

```
web3 = new Web3(web3.setProvider(web3.currentProvider));
```

with:

```
web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
```

---

Also, do not create the `web3` instance before checking for the browser version.

Replace the line:

```
var web3 = new Web3();
```

with:

```
var web3 = window.web3;
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. The line `var web3 = new Web3();` is used in many tutorials and it worked for them. I'm pretty new to js stuff. Can you tell me what's happening in this `var web3 = window.web3;` line?

Comment: @UchihaMadara By using that `var web3 = new Web3()`, you basically overwrite the option to check for the browsers version. Your `typeof web3 !== 'undefined'` check would only check the browser/metamask version properly if you did `typeof window.web3 !== 'undefined'`. It also didn't make much sense to initiate a `new Web3` instance on the second line when your `if/else` statement does it anyways.

Comment: @ReyHaynes it doesn't work and even throws an additional error with your suggestions